# Re-Posted Average value of Normal distribution table question

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mean

Re-posted this question, because after I created my account, the other question acts like it doesn't belong to me. Apologies if there was a way to tie that original question to my new account. Original question: [Average value of Normal distribution table question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502956/average-value-of-normal-distribution-table-question)

I hope this rewording of the question is more clear:

I have a normal distribution table for items looted in a video game, with 13 separate entries for items able to be looted. In my below example, each item has a mean value and a standard deviation.

I can calculate the random variable of any individual item , since I know the Mean and SD. I.E.

I am trying to find the correct way of calculating the probability of looting any random one of these items with a specific probability. In this case, the probability of the value being < than the random variable is 0.05... or 1 in 20 of that item will be looted with that random variable.

I am using the following calculator to find the individual items' random variable, given said probability: https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx

For example, the Cumulative probability: P(X < 60474.549) = 0.05 of item with Mean 72380 and SD 7238 = 60474.549

Mean value and Standard deviation for each item below:

```
Mean     SD      
72380   7238    Cumulative probability: P(X < 60474.549) = 0.05
62040   6204    Cumulative probability: P(X < 51835.328) = 0.05
59455   5945.5  Cumulative probability: P(X < 49675.523) = 0.05
62040   3102    Cumulative probability: P(X < 56937.664) = 0.05
77550   7755    Cumulative probability: P(X < 64794.160) = 0.05
62040   6204    Cumulative probability: P(X < 51835.328) = 0.05
67210   6721    Cumulative probability: P(X < 56154.939) = 0.05
67210   6721    Cumulative probability: P(X < 56154.939) = 0.05
72380   7238    Cumulative probability: P(X < 60474.549) = 0.05
67210   6721    Cumulative probability: P(X < 56154.939) = 0.05
77550   7755    Cumulative probability: P(X < 64794.160) = 0.05 
62040   6204    Cumulative probability: P(X < 51835.328) = 0.05
87550   8755    Cumulative probability: P(X < 73149.307) = 0.05
```

Is it correct to take the average value of each Mean and SD, to find the probability of looting any item with that stat value? Or is there a a more complex statistical calculation that needs to be performed?

Example of what I think I might need to do, which could be wrong: I added the sum of the mean values and then divide by the number of items, then do the same for the standard deviations.

If I take the individual calculations and then average them that after the fact, I get the same result for the random variable.

The average of all the mean values came to 68973.46153846154  and the average of all the Standard Deviations came to 6658.730769230769, and the standard distribution calculator comes back with the the following.

Average Mean = 68973.46153846154
Average SD = 6658.730769230769

Cumulative probability: P(X < 58020.824) = 0.05

Or is there another, more complex calculation that has to be performed in order to calculate the probability of any one of these items being looted with said probability?

If it helps clarify what I'm trying to do. The game is a space game, and you can loot items such as shields, engines, guns, etc. Each one has a known mean mass value and a known standard deviation.

So, the part with the best probability of looting a low mass is the one with mean=59455 and SD=5945.5, which gives a 0.05 probability of looting one of that item below 49675.523 mass as the random variable. The worst one to loot is the one with mean value of 87550 and SD of 8755.

However, since there are 13 potential items that can be looted, we're trying to calculate for the probability of looting ANY ONE of those items, not just the best one or the worst one.

Comment: The other question doesn't belong to you because you've created 2 accounts. You can merge the 2 accounts by following these steps: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous Account 1: https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/306957/nathan-mills Account 2: https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/306930/nathan-mills

Comment: That's just it, I thought I was creating the account while on the page. I'll try and figure it out, but that guide is expecting I know two different logins... which I never created.